# Why are my inception-v3 (in Keras) predictions all wrong?

Tags: machine-learning, keras, conv-neural-network, imagenet

I am an ML beginner and simply implementing inception-v3 using the ImageNet weights. This is my first run at it. My implementation is in Keras. My predictions are all wrong and I need a little foot up, to see what the problem is. It is actaully pretty difficult to find an example of inception-v3 used from top to bottom using Keras online. Most are tutorials on transfer learning. Here is my code.

```
import keras as k
from keras.applications.inception_v3 import InceptionV3
from keras.applications.imagenet_utils import preprocess_input, decode_predictions
from keras.preprocessing import image
import cv2
import numpy as np

model = k.applications.inception_v3.InceptionV3(include_top=True, weights='imagenet', input_tensor=None, input_shape=None)

im = 'images/cat.jpg'
cv2.imread(im).shape
```

(168, 299, 3)

```
im = cv2.resize(cv2.imread(im), (299, 299)).astype(np.float32)
im = np.expand_dims(im, axis=0)
im.shape
```

(1, 299, 299, 3)

```
preds = model.predict(im)
print('Predicted:', decode_predictions(preds
```

Predicted: [[('n03047690', 'clog', 1.0), ('n01924916', 'flatworm', 7.0789714e-11), ('n03950228', 'pitcher', 2.1705252e-11), ('n02841315', 'binoculars', 4.1622389e-13), ('n06359193', 'web_site', 3.8697981e-16)]]

Could someone suggest how this most basic of implementations is wrong. Perhaps my input shape is incorrect?

Answer (score 0):

The inception-v3 model requires that you run your image through `preprocess_input()` before predicting.

add:

```
im=preprocess_input(im)
```

Also, you should import `preprocess_input` from `keras.applications.inception_v3` and not `from keras.applications.imagenet_utils`